# Grails 1.3.6 - Object fields seem to lose their value

Tags: variables, grails

I am a newbie to Grails and using an ancient version of Grails (1.3.6/8). I have an object with some variables that aren't holding on to the stuff I assign them.

```
class NiftyController {

    try
    {
        SomeGrid someGrid = new SomeGrid()
        def selectedDate = params.specifiedDate
        ...
        someGrid.selectedDate = selectedDate
        someGrid.longDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
        println someGrid.selectedDate // prints, say, 08/06/2012
        println someGrid.longDate // prints, say, 1302558890256
        ....
        doSomeWork(someGrid)
    }


    def doSomeWork = { SomeGrid someGrid ->
        println someGrid.selectedDate // prints '' (empty)
        println someGrid.longDate // prints 8 - the number for the current month.
    }
}
```

I am totally scratching my head - I work with Java and this type of loss of assigned variable data is new and makes no sense to me at all. Can anyone figure out what is going on here? I would guess it is some kind of visibility problem unique to Grails, but I can't nail it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is that "try" block? Is it insides of some action/method? Is there anything between `println someGrid.longDate` and `doSomeWork(someGrid)`?

Answer (score 0):

If `doSomeWork` doesn't itself need to be a controller action, I would make it a normal method instead of a closure:

```
private doSomeWork(SomeGrid someGrid) {
  //...
}
```

With it as a closure, Grails may be treating the `SomeGrid` parameter as a command object and trying to data-bind it directly from the `params`.